# Validating a properties file with awk

Tags: regex, awk

I'm using awk to validate a properties file and output only the correct lines. I'm using multiple delimiters in the properties file.

Here is the sample:

```
host1:/var/tmp/dir1/,host2:/var/tmp/dir2/
host2:/var/tmp/dir2/abc.tgz,host3:/var/tmp/

#example of wrong format
host1::/var/tmp/dir1,host2:/var/tmp/
host1:/var/tmp/dir1,:host2:/var/tmp/
```

My delimiters are as shown in the first line of properties file above are `:,:` only in the same format and should appear only once.

Here is the awk code that I'm trying to execute but it always returns error in line for me.

```
#!/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{
    FS=":,:"
}
{
    if ($0 ~/\[(.*)?([^%]*%[^%])(.*)?([^%]*%[^%])(.*)?([^%]*%[^%])]/) {  
        print "validated line " $0
        next
    } else {
        print "error in line " $0

    };

}
```

Am I missing something here ? or is my regex too simple to capture the line ?

and the output is always

error in line host1:/var/tmp/dir1/,host2:/var/tmp/dir2/
error in line host2:/var/tmp/dir2/abc.tgz,host3:/var/tmp/

Comment: You say you are getting an error. Perhaps you should show it to us?

Comment: Also why are you comparing against `FS`?

Comment: What validation, exactly, do you need to do here? Count of fields? Field names? Field values?

Comment: None of your example lines contain the sequence `[:,:]`, which is the only string which your regular expression matches.

Comment: Code which doesn't do at all what you expect needs to be explained in terms of what you do expect. We may be better than your computer at reading your thoughts, but only marginally.

Comment: @EtanReisner, I corrected my last used script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is flawed. You need to write a regular expression to describe the format of the whole line. In order for us to help you do that, you need to describe the correct format. A guess would be something like this:

```
/^[[:alnum:]]+:[[:alnum:]\/\.]+,[[:alnum:]]+:[[:alnum:]\/\.]+$/
```

Where `[[:alnum:]]+` means one or more alphanumeric characters and `[[:alnum:]\/\.]+` also matches a `/` or `.`.

Then the script would be:

```
/^[[:alnum:]]+:[[:alnum:]\/\.]+,[[:alnum:]]+:[[:alnum:]\/\.]+$/ {
    print "valid: " $0
    next
}
{
    print "invalid: " $0
}
```

Instead of using `[[:alnum:]]`, you could enforce the requirement that the delimiters only appear in the specified order using a pattern such as this:

```
/^[^:,]+:[^:,]+,[^:,]+:[^:,]+$/
```

Comment: An approach that lets awk split the fields is a reasonable one. Especially if the field-validation differs by field or is simpler to write as a test of a single field.

Comment: @Etan I can see that it might also be useful to check the fields individually but it seems to me that the whole line must be validated first, otherwise it is impossible to know whether the different delimiters occur in the right order.

Comment: I think it depends on what the possible legal values are for they keys and values, but yes. Ultimately anything that doesn't duplicate the splitting/etc. logic of the final consumer is likely "broken".

Answer (score 1):

In order to catch `::` or `:,` (by extension it will also check `,:` and `,,`) you can define your FS as [:,] and check for empty fields.  A simplistic validation can be (using your input file)

```
$ awk -F"[:,]" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                    if($i=="") 
                       print "error on field " i " --> " $0}
               ' file
error on field 2 --> host1::/var/tmp/dir1,host2:/var/tmp/
error on field 3 --> host1:/var/tmp/dir1,:host2:/var/tmp/
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something more like this:

```
BEGIN {FS=":"}
NF==3 && split($2,a,",")==2 {print "validated line " $0;next}
{print "error in line " $0}
```